# Minor traveling without parents from USA to Sweden

Tags: usa, sweden, minors

My 15 year old daughter will be visiting Sweden and Denmark in July accompanied by her grandparents. Airlines is SAS. Does she need a minor authorization travel document?

I thought it would be a good idea for the parents to write a letter and get it notarized, but is this required? Where can I find a sample letter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I called the airline and they said an authorization is not necessary, but recommended.

My question was because some countries do require an authorization from parents, because of child traffic.

So I will probably write a letter and have it notarized, just in case.

Better safe than sorry.

Comment: You may want to include (or as separate letter) that the grant parents have authority in case of a medical emergency (if you are willing to grant them that, that is.)

Comment: I would also point out that you are allowed to accept your own answer.

Comment: All my kids have done US<->Germany that around that age. We never used a letter and didn't have any problems.